# Wrap/unwrap through Parcel library a RealmList inside one RealmObject within another RealmObject

Tags: android, realm, realm-list, parceler

I have a RealmObject which contains for example these fields:

```
@PrimaryKey
String id;

JustRealmObject justRealmObject;

@ParcelPropertyConverter(SomeRealmObjectParcelConverter.class)    
RealmList<SomeRealmObject> someRealmObjects;

ProblemRealmObject problemObject;
```

And with the first 3 fields everything is fine, they're wrapping and unwrapping as should when I pass the main `RealmObject` to another activity in an intent.

A `ProblemRealmObject` has next fields:

```
@PrimaryKey
String name;

@ParcelPropertyConverter(NeededRealmObjectParcelConverter.class)
RealmList<NeededRealmObject> neededRealmObjects;
```

And here I have a problem. The field `name` wraps/unwraps, but `neededRealmObjects` doesn't. I always get `null` when trying to get this list after unwrapping the main `RealmObject`.
For a `RealmList` I use a `RealmListParcelConverter` and it works great if `RealmList` is inside the the main `RealmObject`, but it's not even calling in the case when the `RealmList` is in the `ProblemRealmObject` within the main `RealmObject`...

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Have you tried copying the object from the Realm first with 2 depth?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce what do you mean? Copying the main object and the `ProblemRealmObject` separately and then insert the second into the first one and pass to an `Intent`? This will impose an additional complexity on the algorithm and passing a parcel object will lose its meaning... I use the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter ` and clicking on an item in the list I already get the required object without having to refer to the database manually each time.

Comment: No, like `realm.copyFromRealm(mainObject, 2)` although it might be 3. Although for sending data between activities, with Realm, passing primary key is preferred.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't use `copyFromRealm(...)` method because of using the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, for which I pass a `RealmResults`. In any case, thank you for the reply, I'll pass a primary key since there is no another way.